# How is a non branching instruction stream loaded from L1 i$

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Question is, does it have to wait 4 cycles for each instruction, or does it wait 4 cycles only once per cache line.

For a specific example, say I have this function in L2.

```
void add_many_things() {
array[2][5] = array[1][3] + array[4][2];
array[1][2] = array[9][5] + array[8][1];
// Going for 20 000 lines.
}
```

I am taught I have to wait 12 cycles to load from L2. 12 cycles per what? Is the question. Does it first spend 8 cycles to load to L1 and then 4 cycles to load from L1. Then the real mystery never talked about, is there a magic register, holding one cache line that the decoder accesses with zero latency, such that it waits four cycles, only once, per cache line. Or is there no magic cache line register and the decoder have to wait 4 cycles for every instruction?

Hypothetically, assuming array is in L1d and add_many_things() is in L2, would I bottleneck on loading the instructions fast enough? I assume add will be in the loop cache but it must still see the next instruction to know to use the loop$ and the indices must be loaded.

To empathize the core question, does x86 load the cache line somewhere before it can be used with zero latency?

Does load and store buffers have anything to do with this?

Comment: No x86-64 CPU I'm aware of has used a split L2 cache.  Only L1 is split into L1i and L1d.  Also, why is this tagged C++?  CPUs run machine code, so it matters exactly what asm your compiler made from that source.

Comment: Anyway, instruction-fetch happens in blocks of 16 or 32-bytes, with a queue between fetch and pre-decode (length / boundary finding) and another before actual decode, assuming it misses in the uop cache.  See https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/3/.  Also https://agner.org/optimize/.  L1i misses fetch from L2; I assume multiple misses can be in flight at once thanks to branch prediction (which has to predict the next fetch-block address, given the current one, long before decode confirms existence of branches.)

Comment: It sounds to me like the queue you mention is the "magic register" I asked about. Meaning it waits 4 cycles_ish only once per load to the queue.

Comment: I'll accept that as an answer, thank you Peter.

Comment: *Meaning it waits 4 cycles_ish only once per load to the queue* Instruction-fetch is pipelined.  Instruction fetch bandwidth from L2 cache is better than 16 bytes per 4 cycles, probably closer to 16 bytes per 2 cycles *on average* on fairly recent microarchitectures like Skylake, maybe also Sandybridge or even earlier.  But it will depend on the microarchitecture and how many outstanding cache misses it can keep in flight.

Comment: https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ has some real-world measurements from Zen 4, bandwidth vs. loop size for 8-byte NOPs. -  *Zen 4, Zen 3, and Golden Cove can all sustain approximately 16 bytes per cycle from L2, and slightly above 10 bytes per cycle from L3*

Comment: Also, you know decode is parallel, right?  Like Intel since Core 2 decoding up to 4 instructions per clock cycle.  (Wider front-ends require uop-cache hits to stay fed, although recent Intel can produce up to 5 uops from the 4 decoders if the one that lands in the complex decoder is multi-uop.)

Comment: Very useful info, thank you. I will profile later. I am trying to decide if it is better to loop over a few adds and stream in the indices from data cache or put the indices in the instructions directly. It feels obvious that there is a (pre)decode queue after you said it, It just did not click for me earlier, even if I knew about the queues. I needed some help. Since I do only add I will hit uop-cache. I suspected that the bottleneck would be to feed predecode from L2. When you say decode is parallel, does that mean predecode is parallel too?

Comment: Yes, of course; as https://agner.org/optimize/ shows, with short average instruction length you can runs at least 4 instructions per clock cycle even with uop-cache misses.  Again, look at the diagrams in https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/3/ and/or https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ or whatever other write-up about whatever CPU you're tuning for, like https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2